Optimisation using the constraint giving very different results from different packages
I am trying find optimal values of parameters with a number of non-linear constraints, as follows
Data
set.seed(1)
A = 1.34; B = 0.5673; C = 6.356; D = -1.234
x = seq(0.5, 20, length.out = 500)
y = A + B * x + C * x^2 + D * log(x) + runif(500, 0, 3)
Rand_Data = data.frame(x = x, Val = y)

Optimisation problem
MyFN = function(a, b, c, d) return(a + b * Rand_Data$x + c * Rand_Data$x^2 + d * log(Rand_Data$x))

Now I want to estimate the parameters a, b, c, d that minimises the sum of absolute difference between Rand_Data$Val and the fitted value with below constraints

Fitted value for the 100th position from MyFN should be less than 120 i.e. MyFN[100] < 120
The difference between sum of fitted value and sum of observed MyFN$Val should be less that 0.001

Optimal solution
Optimisation using pracma package (provided as solution by @ThomasIsCoding)
library(pracma)
eps <- 1e-4
X <- cbind(1, x, x^2, log(x))
f <- function(theta) {
  sum(abs(X %*% theta - y))
}
A <- X[100, , drop = FALSE]
b <- 120 - eps
hin <- function(theta) {
  abs(sum(X %*% theta) - sum(y)) - 1e-3 + eps
}
sol = fmincon(rep(0, 4), f, A = A, b = b, hin = hin)$par
sol #774.972960   318.128595     4.354805 -1798.378655

Optimisation using nloptr packagelibrary(nloptr)
Hx <- function(theta) {
    X[100, , drop = FALSE] %*% theta - (120 - eps)
}
print(nloptr(rep(0, 4), f, eval_g_ineq = hin, eval_g_eq = Hx, opts = list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA", "xtol_rel"=1.0e-8))) 

#0.3596822 -0.8529221 6.461235 0.03229311

As can be seen that these two routines are giving very different optimal solution.
Could you please help to figure out why the optimal solutions are such different? How can I fix that?
Session information
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS 15.1.1

...

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] nloptr_2.1.1 pracma_2.4.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] MASS_7.3-60.2  compiler_4.4.0 quadprog_1.5-8 NlcOptim_0.6  


Could you test the output of f from solved theta by two approaches?

@ThomasIsCoding With your previous code with(   res,   abs(sum(Val) - sum(Val_est)) < 1e-3 & Val_est[100] < 2 ) it fails i.e. generates FALSE

I'm not fluent in the r syntax you are using, but... (1) you are solving non-linear problems here so there is no guarantee that the solvers will converge to the same minima (general characteristic of NL problems).  (2) your problem appears to be linearizable as the only nonlinear action is the ABS() function, which can be made linear, probably with the introduction of more variables and constraints.

@DanielLobo no, you should use Val_est[100] < 120 to verify it

You should print the results of the optimization, not just the final parameter estimates that were returned.  For nloptr, they clearly show that optimization failed:  "Optimization stopped because maxeval (above) was reached."

Did either method report any diagnostics? I don't think both methods converged to a solution thus the results provided were just random numbers from the iterations. If you attempt to plot both solutions to see how quickly they diverge from the the data.  The optimization function abs(sum(X %*% theta) - sum(y)) is likely incorrect, the sum of the absolute differences is a better choice.
